# Formatting date and time inputs into Date object

Tags: java, html, date, input

Using HTML for client side and JAVA for server side, Im trying to convert **two** text inputs into a ***Date*** object in java.
my first input should hold the date in format *DD/MM/YYYY*
and my second should have time *HH:MM* formatted.

What ive tried was using input *type="text"* for both, but im unable to form the object properly on the server's side.

Could you please provide me a simple example for doing that properly? 
Please ignore any validations and of course and you can assume my main problem is the parsing itself.

Comment: Is this a Java question? Or did you want javascript?

Comment: Ive updated, Java on the server's side.

Comment: Parse them via the `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: how do you that while combining them both and keeping only single Date object?

Comment: Grab both of them, concatenate the data into a string or something, then parse them according to a certain format which you specified beforehand which matches the pattern of the string you created from both of the values. There's a reference to the patterns: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Check the Example section there for actual examples containing both date and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) (even a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)) like so

```
private static String DATE_PART = "dd/MM/yyyy";
private static String HOUR_PART = "HH:mm";
private static java.text.DateFormat FORMAT = 
    new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(DATE_PART + " " + HOUR_PART);
private static java.text.DateFormat HOUR_FORMAT = 
    new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(HOUR_PART);
private static java.text.DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = 
    new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(DATE_PART);

public static Date fromStrings(String date, String time) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(date);
    sb.append(" ").append(time);
    try {
        return FORMAT.parse(sb.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String date ="09/01/2014";
    String time ="16:05";
    java.util.Date dt = fromStrings(date, time);
    System.out.println(dt);
    System.out.println(DATE_FORMAT.format(dt));
    System.out.println(HOUR_FORMAT.format(dt));
}
```

Which outputs

```
Thu Jan 09 09:28:00 EST 2014
09/01/2014
16:05
```

Comment: hmm, there's a slight bug, i tried DD/MM/YYYY and HH:MM instead of your pattern and while using the fromString im getting something bit different then what ive expected

Comment: Read the [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) again (it's documented at that link).. "MM" is month in year, "mm" is minutes of day (and capitalization is significant).

Comment: So it might be not related to your solution but to my understanding. I used "09/01/2014" and "16:05" and recieved a corrected "2014-01-09T16:05:00+02:00" object. now, while trying to formating it i used: new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").format(date); but i recieved as a result: 09/01/2014 16:01, Ain't sure about why the 01 appears at the end.

Comment: It works for me - `String date ="09/01/2014";` and 
  `String time ="16:05";` and
  `java.util.Date dt = fromStrings(date, time);` outputs `Thu Jan 09 16:05:00 EST 2014`.

Comment: Your logic is correct but after im getting a Date object I'm trying to string it back to a separated form using SimpleDateFormat. Am I missing something?

Comment: I edited my answer to demonstrate splitting the Date back into two strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
String date = "dd/MM/yyyy"; // your date value from user input
String hour = "HH:mm"; // your hour value from user input    

try {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

    String tempDate = date + " " + hour;
    Date result = dateFormat.parse(tempDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Extract it into a method if you wish.